# TimescaleDB / PostgreSQL daily maximums with timezone offset

Tags: postgresql, group-by, timescaledb

I have problem in sorting & querying data with timezone offset.

I have PostgreSQL + TimescaleDB where I have time series data. Target is to get daily maximums based on local time zone.
My data is in UTC but query needs to be in local timezone as my cumulative counters are resetting in local time.

Target is to have result as in below

```
  id   |    time    |      dailymax    |        name
-------+---------------------+------------------+------------------------
 10001 | 2020-01-05 |                0 | Property1
 10002 | 2020-01-05 | 20930.3490579984 | Property2
 10003 | 2020-01-05 | 28347.1322223556 | Property3
 10001 | 2020-01-04 | 57872.3274949118 | Property1
 10002 | 2020-01-04 | 101159.612050399 | Property2
 10003 | 2020-01-04 |  34113.226521315 | Property3
 10001 | 2020-01-03 |                0 | Property1
 10002 | 2020-01-03 | 17386.2914203308 | Property2
 10003 | 2020-01-03 | 160599.774657208 | Property3
```

My best guess has been so far query in below, but it gives me also records from wrong days and takes long to execute

```
SELECT table.id, CAST(datetime AS DATE) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as time, MAX(value) AS value, map.tagname FROM table
                      JOIN map ON table.id = map.id
                        WHERE table.id in(10003,10029,10008,10036,10007) AND datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= '2019-12-30T16:09:32.080Z' AND datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' < '2020-01-06T16:09:32.080Z'
                    GROUP BY table.id, map.tagname, time
                    ORDER BY time DESC;
```

With TimescaleDB tried something as in below with bad luck as well

```
SELECT table.id, to_char(time_bucket('24 hours', datetime) at time zone 'utc', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') as time, max(value) as value, map.name FROM
    table JOIN map ON table.id = map.id
    WHERE table.id in(10001,10002) AND datetime >= '2020-01-01' AND datetime < '2020-01-10'
GROUP BY time, table.id, map.name ORDER BY time DESC`;
```

Comment: In general only change needed in example is probably to substract result time's by 5 hours to prevent wrong days appear

Comment: Probably last_value could also make magics?